# Type of the derivative operator: linear maps and limit definition

Tags: calculus, linear-transformations, type-theory

I [stumbled upon](https://youtu.be/FtnkqIsfNQc?t=585) the type of the derivative operator for functions from $S$ to $T$ as

$$\partial : (S \to T) \to S \to (S \multimap T)$$

where $S \multimap T$ is a linear map from $S$ to $T$. I think that type convincing. $d$ takes a function $f : S \to T$ and returns a different linear map depending on where in the domain of $f$ the derivative of $\partial f$ is evaluated. However, this does not seem to match with the limit definition of the derivative. There the type of $\partial$ is $S \to T$:

$$\partial f = \frac{d f}{d x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} : S \to T$$

Can you elaborate on this type mismatch between the limit definition and the "linear map definition"?

Answer (score 1):

That definition give you a number that represent the linear map. The linear map is multiplication by that number. If $f'(x)$ is a number from that limit definition, and $Df(x)$ is the linear map definition, then $((Df)(x))(h)=f'(x)h$

This is important at higher dimension, because it is no longer possible to use the limit definition that way, since it makes no sense to divide by a vector and $h$ is now a vector. So instead, $Df(x)$ is a linear map such that $\lim_{h->0}\frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))-((Df)(x))(h))}{||h||}=0$